# Page_ClientValidate in asp.net always return true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have a simple asp.net webform which always return true for `Page_ClientValidate` and submits the form without validating.

I have made changes based on other articles but i still keeps returning true.

**Sample Code**

```
 <div>
      <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsForm" runat="server" CssClass="validationsum" ValidationGroup="vgFormContact" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" CssClass="input_field" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name field can't be blank" CssClass="css-validator" ControlToValidate="txtFullName" ValidationGroup="vgFormContact"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-style" runat="server" Text="SAVE" ValidationGroup="vgFormContact" OnClientClick="ValidateForm(this);" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>




<script type="text/javascript">   
     function ValidateForm(myButton) {

            // Client side validation
            if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {

                if (Page_ClientValidate("vgFormContact") == false) { 

                    return false;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

</script>
```

I have changed properties for  `CausesValidation="false"` `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` nothing seems to make any difference, I never had such issue before not sure where i am doing wrong.

For simplicity of this problem i have only added one field as an example, and in actual code for trouble shooting i am also doing same i am only validating `txtFullName` for testing `purpose` to check why is returning true

Comment: Your code is working just fine. Is your web.config file have this app setting?
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />    
  </appSettings>

Comment: Problem was solved as issue was due to `jQuery v1.12.4` which i was pulling from another folder not the default folder that is contents. I had removed this from the default folder and was using jquery of the template to avoid any conflict with the plugin..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was solved as issue was due to `jQuery v1.12.4` which i was pulling from another folder not the default folder that is contents. I had removed this from the default folder and was using jquery of the template to avoid any conflict with the plugin..

I was using this one from the template assets folder

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/en/js/jQuery v1.12.4.js"></script>
```

WHen i removed the above line and used the default jquery file it worked.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jQuery v1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Problem seems to be jQuery file was being called

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Do you know **why** this jQuery reference was causing the issue ?

Comment: I am not sure why may be due to conflict when this jQuery file was being called..

Comment: this is not a solution